# Issues with up & ifdown ifup: couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces"

Tags: 16.04, wireless, wired

After removing the network-manager package & removing resolvconf application so I could manage my `/etc/network/interfaces` with ifup & ifdown along with manually manage my `/etc/resolv.conf` file I am receiving the following errors when trying to bring up Ethernet & my wireless interface.

Ethernet interface:

```
root@user-computer:/etc/network# ifup eno1

/etc/network/interfaces:21: unknown or no method and no inherits keyword specified
ifup: couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces"
```

wireless interface wlp3s0:

```
root@user-computer:/etc/network# ifup wlp3s0

/etc/network/interfaces:21: unknown or no method and no inherits keyword specified
ifup: couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces"
```

Here are the steps after doing a reboot of my computer - First when I boot back up my primary Ethernet interface comes shut down:

Step 1:

```
root@user-computer:/home/user# ifconfig

lo Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
RX bytes:240 (240.0 B) TX bytes:240 (240.0 B)
```

: `vibr0` is for my virtualbox.

```
virbr0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:gg
inet addrx.xx.xx.xx Bcastx.xx.255.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Step 2:

Then I will try to bring it up:

```
root@user-computer:/home/user# ifup eno1

/etc/network/interfaces:21: unknown or no method and no inherits keyword specified

ifup: couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces"
```

Step 3:

I read my `/etc/network/interfaces` file to make sure everything looks good:

```
root@user-computer:/home/user# cat /etc/network/interfaces

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#eno1
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
address xx.xx.xx.xx
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway xx.xx.xx.xx
up route add -net xx.xx.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 gw xx.xx.xx.xx
up route add -net xx.xx.0.0 netmask 255.128.0.0 gw xx.xx.xx.xx
up route add -net xx.xx.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 gw xx.xx.xx.xx
up route add -net xx.xx.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 gw xx.xx.xx.xx
dns-nameservers xx.xx.xx.xx xx.xx.xx.xx xx.xx.xx.xx
dns-search local1.local local2.local local2.local local3.local local4.local

# wlp3s0
auto wlp3s0
iface wlp3s0 inet statc
address xx.xx.xx.xx
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway xx.xx.xx.xx
wireless-essid xxxx
wireless-mode managed
```

Step 4:

I can bring the interface up with `ifconfig eno1 up`:

```
root@user-computer:/home/user#ifconfig eno1 up

root@user-computer:/home/user# ifconfig

eno1 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
Interrupt:20 Memory:f7d00000-f7d20000
```

Step 5:

The only way I can get the interface running is to run `dhclient eno1`:

```
root@user-computer:/home/user# dhclient eno1

root@user-computer:/home/user# ifconfig

eno1 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
inet addrx.xx.xx.xx Bcastx.xx.xx.xx Mask:255.255.255.0
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:1535 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:1274 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:1963415 (1.9 MB) TX bytes:108139 (108.1 KB)
Interrupt:20 Memory:f7d00000-f7d20000
```

Other Issues:

Trying to bring up WiFi:

```
root@user-computer:/home/user/Downloads# ifup wlp3s0

/etc/network/interfaces:21: unknown or no method and no inherits keyword specified

ifup: couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces"

root@user-computer:/home/user/Downloads# ifconfig wlp3s0 up

SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not possible due to RF-kill
```

Final:

I need to have control over my network interfaces with ifup && ifdown with the `/etc/network/interfaces` file along with control over my `/etc/resolv.conf` file:

Now my dhclient is overwriting resolv.conf again - and I specifically removed resolvconf package to stop this behavior.

Is this a bug or what is going on and how do I resolve this issue to get ifup & ifdown working for Ethernet & WiFi interfaces.

Comment: Start by correcting the typo in your interfaces file: `iface wlp3s0 inet statc` (should be `static`)

Comment: I believe `up` must either be `pre-up` or `post-up`, not just "up." Also, you must specify the wpa-psk for the wireless. Finally, wireless-mode managed is probably superfluous.